# Why am I getting this perl Net::Async::HTTP warning?

Tags: perl, asynchronous, https

In this oversimplified script I'm doing a GET request with [Net::Async::HTTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Async::HTTP) using [IO::Async::Loop::EV](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async::Loop::EV):

```
use Modern::Perl '2017';
use IO::Async::Loop::EV;
use Net::Async::HTTP;
use Future;

my $loop = IO::Async::Loop::EV->new;
my $http = Net::Async::HTTP->new(max_redirects => 0);
$loop->add($http);

my $f = $http->GET('https://www.perl.org')
->then(sub {
        my $response = shift;
        printf STDERR "got resp code %d\n", $response->code;
        return Future->done;
    });
$http->adopt_future($f->else_done);

$loop->run;
```

I get this warning a couple of times:

```
EV: error in callback (ignoring): Can't call method "sysread" on an undefined value at .../IO/Async/Stream.pm line 974
```

I get this warning when using [IO::Async::Loop::Event](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async::Loop::Event) too (again in [IO::Async::Stream](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/PEVANS/IO-Async-0.71/lib/IO/Async/Stream.pm), at line 974).

For non-secure (http) links, however, all looks good. So something's probably wrong with [IO::Async::SSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Async::SSL). (I tried this on different machines, with different OS - still getting those warnings)

Why am I getting this warning multiple times? Does it occur on your machines too?

Comment: Does the warning omit the file name and line number?

Comment: @choroba Edited. Warning is at line 974 in IO::Async::Stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this warning is specific to the `IO::Async::Loop::EV` implementation. If you just

```
use IO::Async::Loop;
my $loop = IO::Async::Loop->new;
```

then it appears to work just fine. Unless you're picking that for a specific purpose it's best to avoid it and just let the `IO::Async::Loop->new` magic constructor find a good one.

Additionally, rather than ending the script with

```
$loop->run
```

You could instead use

```
$f->get
```

so it performs a blocking wait until that `Future` is complete but then exits cleanly afterwards, so as not to have to `<Ctrl-C>` it to abort.

---

I've raised this as a bug against IO::Async::Loop::EV at https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=124030